# Imagick :: scaleImage feature issue (black background)

Tags: php, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I am planning to change image resolution with Imagick plugin and using scaleImage. Firsty is there any way i can improve image quality. Secondly 
After converting resolution, scaleimage change background color from white as  black background. i have attached image below. Any help would be highly appreciated

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($img);
$image->scaleImage(1920,1080);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I imagine `$img` holds layers, transparency, or doesn't have a defined background/matte.

Try the following...

```php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($img);
$image->setBackgroundColor('WHITE');
$image->flattenImages();
$image->scaleImage(1920,1080);
```

Comment: Adding a bit more here -- You probably would get better quality using resizeImage()

Comment: FlattenImages() is depreciated now, use mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN)